# Rails 4 assets manifest.json recent digest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, manifest, assets, sprockets

I have a few manifest files with digest on the deploy server

```
manifest-bcba79cf9483d404e9951992bbe38e46.json
manifest-7db402a1216c2425e0f881b6331ba27d.json
...
```

How sprockets know which of manifests is recent?
Or it should be only one manifest file?

Regards

Comment: i think it will use fingerprint for that and finger print contains the timestamp also. so it can find out which one is newest

Answer (score 5):

the `manifest.json` always has a random `SecureRandom.hex(16)` attached to it's name. Taking a look at [`manifest`](https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/master/lib/sprockets/manifest_utils.rb#L23) you can see that Sprockets takes the first available file.

If you see multiple `manifest-*.json` files on your server, it *might* get risky since Sprockets doesn't really choose the newest file and you may end up with loading outdated assets.

Just run the following and you're good to go:

```
bundle exec rake assets:clobber
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Comment: I don't see any code in Sprockets::Asset that determines which of many manifest-<digest>.json files are loaded by rails though. How it determines which is the most recent.

Comment: @noodl I added the step by step explanation. It is not that Sprocket pulls the newest file out of a pool of files. It calculates the digest of the asset that you need.

Comment: Sorry if I'm not clear but there are multiple manifest files. Several json files each containing manifest information and the wrong one of those is being used. In the manifest is contained the digest of the current file for any given path, in the assets: {} section. manifest isn't a file that's being linked to like a javascript file or something.

Comment: https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/blob/master/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb#L50 suggests that if there are many, it'll take the first one alphabetically which is what we're seeing. So then either there should only ever be one manifest file or we need to specify a constant path to the manifest file so it doesn't just guess.

Comment: @noodl You last comment made it clear to me. I just added that part and now I see you have already found it yourself :(

Comment: Well since you can now see what the OP is asking too, if you update and answer just that part (many manifests confuse rails; don't do that) you can have the bounty :)

Comment: @noodl that's indeed very kind of you. I have removed the unrelated part and now we only have the **real** answer!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69904/discussion-between-yan-foto-and-noodl).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should only have one manifest file. Try to invalidate the whole cache by increasing your asset version in your `production.rb` file like so:

```
config.assets.version = "1.x"
```